# Can't uninstall an app in android which is showing ads frequently

Tags: applications, uninstallation

An app is showing ads frequently on my device. I can't find it in the app collection. I also tried Settings -> Device Administration but didn't get it there. Then I looked for it in Xender (app like ShareIt) and got it there . Its name is Shuffle but can't uninstall it even from there.

Comment: Is this the app? : ***[Shuffle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dodgybits.android.shuffle&hl=en)***

Comment: I don't know but the xender shows it with the name of shuffle in app section.

Comment: Try this app to help remove it : App Manager - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar same problem and solved it this way:

1. Go to Settings → Device Manager → uncheck unknown app
2. Go to Setting → Apps → uninstall the first unnamed app from the list

Answer (score 1):

Settings>Device Administrator... Then deselect the "ghost" app and it will allow for you to uninstall through application manager as other apps do. Basically it snuck in and gave itself administrative properties, not allowing for it to be removed. I refuse to factory reset my device, lol

Answer (score 0):

There will be application named '**android communication**' with android icon uninstall it.Actually I was having the same problem then this shuffel app made one mistake of poping notification which helped me to get its app info and as I got app info it was easy just uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN TRY
    (1ST PROCESS) "SETTINGS>APPS>(LOOK FOR AN UNIDENTIFIED APP)>UNINSTALL".

```
IF 1ST PROCESS NOT WORK,YOU CAN TRY SAFE MODE(HOLD POWER BUTTON,AND WHEN POWER-OFF OPTIONS WILL COME,HOLD "POWER-OFF" OPTION.),THEN TRY 1ST PROCESS.
```

SORRY FOR MY POOR ENGLISH.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently encountered the same issue...I tried to uninstall it from Settings>apps...but couldn't do it cuz it was  disabled. Then I installed an app called "uninstaller" from play store...Upon selecting the blank app to uninstall, it said something like.."can't uninstall as the app is enabled in device administrators"..I had to deselect that blank app in Settings>device administrators.. and then I could able to uninstall that annoying blank app. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

When I turned on my Hudl 2 I got a white screen that popped up displaying an ad. so I went to settings and found a app with no image or name. I couldn't uninstall it . So I found a app called uninstaller from the Play store and downloaded it. I opened up the app and that blank app was at the top of the list I clicked on it and I couldn't install it because it was ticked on device administrator so I unticked it and I could uninstall it

By the way you don't need an uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with "movie HD" app on android
besides not actually having movies to watch, it constantly showed ads even if it was not running.
When I tried to uninstall it the normal way I could not because uninstall was greyed out.
I finally got rid of it by using "AppMgr III" app that showed it had administrator protection. it showed me where to uncheck that and then I was able to uninstall movie HD and ads are finally gone!

YAY for appmgr III, BOO for movie HD

Comment: Could you link this "AppMgr III"?

Comment: I had trouble with "Movie HD" as well and could not delete it from my Samsung Galaxy Tablet so I followed Fred Stevens' advice and it worked. Please don't ever download it. It is a nightmare and the pop ups are relentless.
Thanks for your post, Fred.

Comment: @MatthewRead probably [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) – but there are two more with the same name, so I'm not 100% sure. Hopefully fred can confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Just download superuser apk from Google, then go to delete option. You will find all applications, you can even uninstall built-in apps.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me when I went to device administrators 
Why not factory reset it it will probably go away

Comment: Hello Bia. Whilst I know you do not have enough reputation to comment, making comments such as this as an "answer" will not help.

Answer (score -1):

Just install 360 Security from play store and go and clean your phone. That app detects com.media malware and asks you to deactivate your administrator ... deactivate that and you can automatically uninstall that malware.

- I think 360 Security is best for your phone but you need to avoid ads
- Don't allow it to remove app cache, otherwise it removes your uc downloads and other apps' data.
- Don't download apps from untrusted websites

Comment: Please don't link malware.

Answer (score -1):

App Mgr III really works, was so easy. All I did was click on the ad app and deactivated it, boom, no more endless pop-up ads.

Answer (score -2):

you will have to flash the firmware (reload the software). you can try turning on the phone immediately after it starts to boot, press and hold volume down button. it will start the phone in safe mode. try uninstalling the app there, if unsuccessful, you will have to reload the firmware.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense: when flashing firmware, the current one is overwritten. So either the app was overwritten/removed as well (if it was a system app; in which case one doesn't need to uninstall it), it would be re-installed again (if it's part of the ROM; in which case that flashing is useless), or it wasn't part of system apps at all (in which case flashing was for no good). And if removal from within safe-mode was successful, then why is another reload is required? Shouldn't a simple reboot be sufficient?

Comment: Could it be what you wanted to say was: "Turn the device off, then boot to [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info), try to uninstall the app from there, and then reboot again to get out of safe-mode"? If so, what makes you think this approach might be more successful than the OP's original uninstall attempt?